# How Do I Adjust Indentation Style For Multi-Line Lists?

Tags: indentation, default

The default indentation style in emacs for a multi-line list is as follows:

```
longFunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3,
                 arg4)
```

where the final argument snaps to the starting position of the first argument.

How do I adjust this default indentation style (ie. what do I put in my .emacs) to make the second line snap to some increment of tabbing? I want the final result to look like:

```
longFunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3,
    arg4)
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Java - is there no generic solution though?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Looks like the relevant attribute I was looking for was `arglist-cont-nonempty`. Added this to my `.emacs` file:

```
;; adjust open list indentation
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty 8)))
```